# Why is parent showing child's offsetTop value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div element (parent) which contains another div element (child).

The child element has `margin-top : 30px` set via CSS. When I calculate the `offsetTop` of the parent, it reports `30px` even if the parent does not have any margin set!

What is more weird is that as soon as I put border on the parent, then `offsetTop` works as desired. Please see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J22DT/).

Why does putting a border on the parent alter its `offsetTop` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of [*margin collapsing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

From Mozilla Developer Network :

> **Parent and first/last child**
>
> If there is no border, padding, inline content, or clearance to
>   separate the margin-top of a block with the margin-top of its first
>   child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block
>   with the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse.
>   The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Use `outline` property to see what really happens behind the scenes...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J22DT/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about such a thing. This has been kept me going in circles for hours!